# MYSQL/PHP/JQUERY - Blobs into image gallery, how to solve an issue?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, blob, image-gallery

i have already made a working script that would load previously uploaded Images (with their title, size, category etc.) into a gallery.
It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWASu.jpg

The problem is, i made it load an image of RANDOM ID, there will be more such images after sliding right/left, and i would like to have them displayed by ID, but each other to be the NEXT ID, instead of being this same or random. How could i make it work?

Here is the script so far:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, rozmiar, technika, kategoria, image_time, title FROM {$table} ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    echo '<ul><li>Nie wgrano żadnych plików.</li>';
else
{
    echo '<ul>';
    while(list($id, $rozmiar, $technika, $kategoria, $image_time, $title) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo "<div class='image-frame left-image'>";
        echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?show=$id' data-lightbox='galeria' data-title='{$title}, {$technika} | {$rozmiar}'><img width='450' src='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?show=$id'></a>";
        echo "<div class='description'><p>{$technika}, {$rozmiar}</p></div></div>";
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
        <?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, rozmiar, technika, kategoria, image_time, title FROM {$table} ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    echo '<ul><li>Nie wgrano żadnych plików.</li>';
else
{
    echo '<ul>';
    while(list($id, $rozmiar, $technika, $kategoria, $image_time, $title) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo "<div class='image-frame right-image'>";
        echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?show=$id' data-lightbox='galeria' data-title='{$title}, {$technika} | {$rozmiar}'><img width='450' src='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?show=$id'></a>";
        echo "<div class='description'><p>{$technika}, {$rozmiar}</p></div></div>";
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Any ideas on how may i make it into one script, that would load multiple blocks with images with ascending ID's?
Would be grateful for all suggestions.

Comment: How are you planning to apply class on those retrieved images? I mean, only one would be `left-image` and all others would be `right-image`?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific - i want the Left block, and the Right block to be displayed. Those would show image of ID #1 and ID #2, however there would be an option to slide right, so that the left would become ID #3, the right ID #4. I am having issues with setting the to blocks automatically show the other part of gallery. I've been thinking if there is a way to make a variable, that would also be put into CSS so that each block will  be unique and automated?

Comment: Or maybe should i resign from two blocks, and make one that would just horizontally expand when there are some more images added?

Comment: I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be like this:

- Retrieve all the rows from the table without any `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clause, like this:

  ```
  SELECT id, rozmiar, technika, kategoria, image_time, title FROM {$table}
  ```
- Count total number of rows retrieved and create an empty `$resultArray` array, like this:

  ```
  $rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result);
  $resultArray = array();
  ```
- Loop through the result set and append the rows to the `$resultArray` array, like this:

  ```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $resultArray[] = $row;
  }
  ```
- Use `rand()` function to pick one random row from the `$resultArray` array and implement circular array logic from this `$resultArray` array to achieve your desired result, like this:

  ```
  $i = $randValue = rand(0, $rowCount - 1);
  do{
      list($id, $rozmiar, $technika, $kategoria, $image_time, $title) = $resultArray[$i];
      echo "<div class='image-frame'>";
      echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?show=$id' data-lightbox='galeria' data-title='{$title}, {$technika} | {$rozmiar}'><img width='450' src='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?show=$id'></a>";
      echo "<div class='description'><p>{$technika}, {$rozmiar}</p></div></div>";
      $i = ++$i % $rowCount;
  }while($i != $randValue);
  ```

Here's the complete code,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, rozmiar, technika, kategoria, image_time, title FROM {$table}");

$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result);
$resultArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $resultArray[] = $row;
}

$i = $randValue = rand(0, $rowCount - 1);
do{
    list($id, $rozmiar, $technika, $kategoria, $image_time, $title) = $resultArray[$i];
    echo "<div class='image-frame'>";
    echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?show=$id' data-lightbox='galeria' data-title='{$title}, {$technika} | {$rozmiar}'><img width='450' src='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?show=$id'></a>";
    echo "<div class='description'><p>{$technika}, {$rozmiar}</p></div></div>";
    $i = ++$i % $rowCount;
}while($i != $randValue);
```

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: For now I kept `left-image` and `right-image` out of the equation. You can tweak the code as per your requirement to incorporate those `class` values.

Comment: Woah, that's exactly what i meant!

Comment: Thank you Sir, for both the solution and explaining how it works part by part, works flawlessly for me now. Much grateful!!!